# Adding an alpha channel to a texture file using Arnold 5's Render Selection to Texture in Maya

Tags: python, textures, rendering, maya, render-to-texture

I'm new to Maya so hopefully I can communicate this clearly. I'm using the Arnold 5 utility renderSelectionToTexture to bake a sequence of texture files for a character's face. I need to add an alpha channel containing a mask for the character's mouth. I know that in 5 there's an option to enable AOV's. I'm sure this feature holds the answer but so far I'm not getting the results I'd expect. For starters, it seems that each AOV is baked into a separate file, when I need a single composited texture file. Does anyone have experience with this? Any guidance appreciated.